# What are the utilities included in the Mavericks recovery partition?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, bootcamp, partition, recovery

What is Mavericks Recovery Partition good for? I have Maverick also installed on an external Hard drive, in case something goes wrong with my main system I can use this external hard. Do I still need the recovery partition? (I also have my old Snow Leopard installation disk).

Background:
I have a macbook pro, with Snow Leopard on it. I want to update to Mavericks. Before updating my main system, I put an old hard disk in my mac (same configuration as the main one, with Snow Leopard osx), and updated to Maverick to test the waters!

It went almost well, just it did not create recovery partition since I had 3 partitions on my hard (OSX, bootcamp and a fat32 partition for data).

now, for having the recovery partition, I need to format my hard, and do a fresh install of Snow Leopard, and bootcamp windows, and update to Maverick. Does it worth it?  Or, I forget about the Recovery Partition, and update my current configuration to Mavericks, and in case of any emergency I use the Maverick installed on an Hard drive?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The recovery partition for OS X 10.7 and above includes the following utility applications:

- Firmware Password Utility
- Network Utility
- Disk Utility
- Terminal

In addition, the recovery partition allows you to use a version of Safari to better help you research and diagnose problems, restore from a Time Machine backup, and install OS X.